# How to sum values of an entire column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame with 900 columns I need the sum of each column in pyspark, so it will be 900 values in a list. Please let me know how to do this? Data has around 280 mil rows all binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have the data in a Spark DataFrame, you can use the [`sum`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sum#pyspark.sql.functions.sum) SQL function, together with [DataFrame.agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=agg#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg).

For example:

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 3], [2, 4]], schema=['a','b'])

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
sdf.agg(F.sum(sdf.a), F.sum(sdf.b)).collect()

# Out: [Row(sum(a)=3, sum(b)=7)]
```

Since in your case you have quite a few columns, you can use a list comprehension to avoid naming columns explicitly.

```
sums = sdf.agg(*[F.sum(sdf[c_name]) for c_name in sdf.columns]).collect()
```

Notice how you need to unpack the arguments from the list using the * operator.